# Which RAID controller driver to use for Dell 5/i controller on Poweredge 2900?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, raid

During the installation process of Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS on a Dell PowerEdge 2900, a menu to choose the appropriate driver for my RAID controller came up.  A list of many driver options were given and I can not find documentation for which driver to use.  This menu is directly before the disk partitioning menu.

The model is UCP-51 and also called 5/i in most cases I've seen.

Is there some kind of resource that I can reference to find out which driver I should use?  I'm relatively new to this.

Comment: Looking at https://hwraid.le-vert.net/wiki/LSIMegaRAIDSAS it is the LSI MegaRAID SAS Driver.  Unfortunately, I am not sure where you get the driver for Ubuntu from.

Comment: You might have luck with https://www.broadcom.com/site-search?q=megacli

Comment: @Terrance What makes you think that?  I don't know what makes it seem that this is the driver required based on the page provided.

Comment: The commands are not included in Ubuntu like the comment is stated, like megacli does not come in Ubuntu by default.  I do work in a data center and the images that they push onto the Dell servers have the driver already included.  But the servers with the PERC 5/i are old and getting phased out.  You could possibly get away with downloading the RPM driver and using `alien` to install it.  If you see LSI MegaRAID as an option during install you can try using that.

Comment: @Terrance unfortunately, LSI megaRAID doesn't come in the list of drivers on the disc being booted from.  I also have no idea where to enter those commands or at what phase to do so.  I think I will avoid using that method.  In your opinion, would using a different RAID controller be a wise choice given that the replacement controller would would with the machine and the driver would be within the list of provided drivers to choose from?  There are others like the 6/i and 5/e that can be preinstalled from factory and I may replace it with one of those if the above conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Any of the cards in https://certification.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/category/RAID/?&page=1 should be well supported in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Terrance, thank you very much for your help